# On-street parking Android/iOS application in Boston

Tags: android, ios

I am looking for a parking application in Boston:

- indicate some map which street parking spots can be used by anyone for free ( e.g. no resident-/handicapped-/... only)
- Android or iOS

If possible:

- free
- other cities
- shows my current location
- also displays other parking options (i.e. in addition to on-street parking, I'm also interested in public and private parking.)

[Parknav](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/parknav-street-parking-chicago/id576265949?mt=8) seems pretty good but it doesn't support Boston (Chicago & San Francisco only as of now).

Comment: Not sure for your area (as I'm from a different part of this globe), but maybe my corresponding [parking app-list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_parking) has something?